# Visual studio 2013 performance and diagnostics concurrency does not show call stack

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I ran concurrency option in Visual studio 2013 performance and diagnostics tool and it shows only data Hanlde1 --- Handle(n). But it does not show which function is getting contention. I Ran other CPU sample and instrumentation and it shows profiled data correctly. Please help.